# mock click event and use toBeCalled() got error of not a function error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

This is my attempt to test a button's click event

```
it('should call addItem when button is clicked', () => {
    const addItem = jest.fn()
    const button = mount(<App onClick={addItem} />)
    //button.find('button').props.onClick()
    //expect(addItem).toBeCalled()
  })
```

This the DOM

```
<div className="App">
        <input type="text" onChange={this.changeInput} />
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
```

What's the mistake?

Comment: Try using `button.find('button').simulate('click')`. Also you might want to rename it from `button` to something more appropriate like `wrapper` or `component`.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac almost there, but still can't do assert https://codesandbox.io/s/mk6r923r8

Answer (score 1):

### What to test:

Check if the `addItem` function is getting called when the `add` button is clicked.

### Why the test failed:

**You mocked the wrong function**. `addItem` is an `instance` function defined in your class but what you're testing is a function you passed as `prop` to your component instead.

### How to test a function/method defined in your component:

Either you want to watch a method be called, but keep the original implementation or mock the implementation, but restore the original later after the test run then you can use `jest.spyOn` for either of the two.

If you only wanted to “spy” calls to the `addItem` function, but leave the original implementation in place, then you could do it this way.

```js
it("should call addItem when button is clicked", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "addItem");
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // don't forget to clear the spy
  spy.mockClear();
});
```

If you really want to mock the function, then restore the original implementation afterwards then you can do this.

```js
it("should call addItem when button is clicked", () => {
    const mocked = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, "addItem");
    // override the implementation
    mocked.mockImplementation(() => "mock");
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(mocked).toHaveBeenCalled();

    mocked.mockRestore();
  });
```

See working implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/mm06k8px4y

> Note that in the code, I changed the `addItem` implementation **by manually binding the to the class instead of using arrow functions (class properties)** since we need that function to be in the class prototype for easier testing. Otherwise, it would lead to this error: `Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined` since it's not present in the class prototype.
>
> Also "class properties" are still experimental and and not part of ES6.
>
> See this for more details: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9851

Comment: strange, why I don't see this kind of implementation before? May you guide me to the correct path of frontend unit testing?

Comment: I'll try to help as much as I can with your questions. There's a lot of online resources available on this topic as well so further reading would help. At least, in my case, and practice just like what you're doing now.

Comment: few questions: i) so you don't use arrow function and use bind(this) for the sake of testing? ii) you will have to write that block of code to test each event? eg. onChange, onClick, that's a lot of work..